# Powershell Import-CSV Create new row based on a condition

Tags: powershell, csv, import-csv

I'm somewhat new to scripting in general.  I have a CSV file which I am importing and modifying the data so it presents in a better format.
My question is I want to do (I guess) a foreach loop on all rows of a given column, and if data does not match a certain criteria:

1. Copy the entire row onto a new row (retaining all other data in the
   row).
2. Replace the value of "Column B" with the value of "Column C"

I'm basically doing an `import-csv $file`. I'll export it later on.

Here is an example: I basically want to move Task2 into the Task1 column IF there is any data present except "--", and then I can ignore the Task 2 column.

`Import-csv` gives me this:

```
ID,    TASK1, TASK2
123,    A,     --     
456,    B,     --     
789,    C,     D,     

But I want it to look like this:

ID,   TASK1, TASK2
123,    A ,    --     
456,    B,     --     
789,    C,     D,     
789,    D,     D,
```

Comment: can you post the code you have.

Comment: Its really $CSV = import-csv <path> at the moment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Other method:

```
$data=import-csv "C:\temp\test.txt"
$data + ($data | where TASK2 -ne "--" |  %{$_.TASK1=$_.TASK2;$_})
```

Comment: The above method deleted the original data in the Task1 Column, so I think it would need to add a new row and not affect any of the current rows.

Comment: My code give you the result you hâve given un example. Explain better AND i do it ;)

Comment: actually I take it back, it does work if I just create a new ps object.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For relative small csv files this could be a way ($CSV+= recreates the var each time):

```
## Q:\Test\2017\09\03\SO_46018965.ps1
$CSV = import-csv 'test.csv'
foreach ($Row in $CSV){
    if ($Row.TASK1 -eq 'C'){
        $NewRow=[PSCustomObject]@{
            ID = $Row.ID
            TASK1 = $Row.TASK2
            TASK2 = $Row.TASK2}
        $CSV+=$NewRow
    }
}
$CSV
```

Sample output:

```
ID  TASK1 TASK2
--  ----- -----
123 A     --
456 B     --
789 C     D
789 D     D
```